# Transform to normal Data Frame which has row as list. Split rows to column

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

My Data Frame output from reading a complex json looks like below.

Where individual row is a list within a single column.

Below is the sample Data Frame(`df`)

```
col
[A,1,3,4,Null]
[B,4,5,6,Null]
[C,7,8,9,Null]
```

I tried to split to individual column using pandas but it didnt work as individual row itself is a list. 
I want the data frame to look like below.

```
colA,colB,colC,colD,colE
A    1    3     4    Null
B    4    5     6    Null
C    7    8     9    Null
```

I dont need the column name to specified manually it can be auto-generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html), but first need create nested `list` from values of column `col`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':[['A',1,3,4,'Null'],['B',4,5,6,'Null'],['C',7,8,9,'Null']]})
print (df)
                  col
0  [A, 1, 3, 4, Null]
1  [B, 4, 5, 6, Null]
2  [C, 7, 8, 9, Null]

print (df.col.values.tolist())
[['A', 1, 3, 4, 'Null'], ['B', 4, 5, 6, 'Null'], ['C', 7, 8, 9, 'Null']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.col.values.tolist(), 
                                columns=['colA','colB','colC','colD','colE'])

print(df1)
  colA  colB  colC  colD  colE
0    A     1     3     4  Null
1    B     4     5     6  Null
2    C     7     8     9  Null
```

---

If dont need specify column names:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.col.values.tolist())
print(df1)
   0  1  2  3     4
0  A  1  3  4  Null
1  B  4  5  6  Null
2  C  7  8  9  Null
```

**Timings**:

```
#len(df) = 4k
df = pd.concat([df]*1000).reset_index(drop=True)

In [80]: %timeit pd.DataFrame(df['col'].apply(pd.Series).values, columns=['colA','colB','colC','colD','colE'])
1 loop, best of 3: 753 ms per loop

In [81]: %timeit pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.col.values.tolist(), columns=['colA','colB','colC','colD','colE'])
100 loops, best of 3: 3.73 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a df from the result of using `apply` and `pd.Series` ctor on each row:

```
In [99]:
pd.DataFrame(df['col'].apply(pd.Series).values, columns=['colA','colB','colC','colD','colE'])

Out[99]:
  colA colB colC colD  colE
0    A    1    3    4  Null
1    B    4    5    6  Null
2    C    7    8    9  Null
```